# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ of iterated function $e^{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, chaos-theory

Do you think there's a better way to do this?

Given that $E(x)=e^{x-1}$, $n$ iterates of $E(x)$ are defined as $E(\underbrace{E(E(...(x))...)}_{n-1\text{ times}}=E^{\circ n}(x)$.

Here's my attempt to find (or, rather, justify)  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E^{\circ n}(x)$.

(1) $\lvert E'(x)\lvert=\lvert e^{x-1}\lvert < 1$ if $x<1$, thus any fixed point in this range will be attractive, and so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E^{\circ n}(x)=1$ if $x\le 1$.

(2) $\lvert E'(x)\lvert=\lvert e^{x-1}\lvert > 1$ if $x>1$, thus any fixed point in this range will be repulsive, and so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E^{\circ n}(x)\to \infty$ if $x> 1$.

I think that something is not right with my argument because for $x=1$, $\lvert E'(x) \lvert = 1$, and so we don't know whether the point is attractive or repulsive. And for $\lvert E'(x) \lvert < 1$, there in fact are not any fixed points in the range, since the only fixed point of $E(x)$ is 1.

Comment: Sketch the graph of the function, using calculus to get the right concavity, and trace out a few orbits.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I CAS-checked to see that the limit is $1$ if $x\le 1$ and $+\infty$ else.

Comment: @Ned: how do I trace the orbits analytically?

Comment: draw the graph of the function and of the line $y=x$. For the orbit of $a$, start at the point $(a,a)$, then go vertical to the curve, horizontal to the line, vertical to the curve, horz. to the line, ... I think this is called a web diagram. for simple functions like the one here, you can quickly see the nature of all the orbits by drawing a few.

Comment: I know this, but this is a graphical approach. For finding the limit, I think, that wouldn't be a rigorous argument.

Comment: For this sort of fixed point, you can argue that the orbits are increasing (as sequences) by showing, by calculus, that $f(x)>x$ for $x$ except at $x=1$. Then use that increasing sequences either converge or .... And an orbit of a continuous function can only converge to ....